# Excel - Restore cell data deleted by VBA?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I realised that if the cell data was deleted using VBA, 
you wil not be able to undo it back (Ctrl + Z).
Is there a way to restore back the cell data? (not Worksheet, not file, not talking about backing up files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to suggest the easiest build-in method.

Windows 7 has "Previous Versions" feature that can be used to recover lost data. This works with Excel 2010 and higher version files.

1. Right-click the Excel file and either click 'Properties.' then 'Previous 
   Versions' tab or 'Restore Previous Versions' from the after clicked pop up 
   menu.
2. Select the version of the that you need.
3. Finally Click the 'Restore' button to replace the existing file.

Comment: Yes, I know this method and it is great, but that mainly applies to files? Are there any instant method? [like Undo(Ctrl + Z)]

Comment: Glad to hear from you. Yes this method basically considers the 'Last Saved'. Let me check my backup file, I've some very useful Links. Soon I'll return to you.

Comment: Check this one will help you http://www.jkp-ads.com/Articles/UndoWithVBA00.asp

Comment: Thanks, I was searching up and down for that. Maybe you would like to include that in the answer above?

Comment: I think others could use the link from the comment also :-) .